# Find a parametrization for a line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

We didn't go over how to solve this problem in my class, and I'm trying to piece it together from our textbook and online sources, but I'm still not getting anything.

The question is: Find a parametrization for the line perpendicular to $(2, −1, 1)$, parallel to the plane $2x + y − 4z = 1$, and passing through the point $(1, 0, −3)$.

What I tried doing was saying that the directional vector of $l(t)$ would be perpendicular to $(2, -1, 1)$, so their dot product should equal zero. From this I got $2x-y+z=0$.

I then plugged the point given into $2x + y − 4z = c$, to find the plane that this new line would be on, and got $2x+y-4z=14$.

We were taught to arbitrarily set one of these values $(x, y, z)$ equal to zero, so I chose to do that for z. Then, solving for the remaining variables, I get $x=7/2$ and $y=0$.

Therefore, my equation for the line $l(t)=(1+7t/2, 0, -3)$, but the online homework system is not accepting this. Any help to point out where I went wrong and explain this problem would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: The direction vector of your line should be perpendicular to *both*  $(2,-1,1)$ *and* $(2,1,-4)$. So in what direction should it lie?

Comment: Would the direction it lie in be the cross product of both $(2, -1, 1)$ and $(2,1,-4)$? So in $(-5, -10, 0)$. Then would this be the direction vector of $l(t)$?

Comment: Right, but please check your arithmetic carefuly for the cross product. And do you understand why it must be perpendicular to both of those?

Comment: not completely. The way I was trying to solve the problem, I assumed that the direction vector could only be perpendicular to $(2, -1, 1)$. If you could explain why, I would appreciate it very much! And I realized that I accidentally did the cross product backwards (I should have gotten $(3, 10, 4)$ instead). :D

Comment: For the line to be parallel to a plane, its direction vector must be perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane. :)

Answer (score 2):

The line passes through $(1, 0, -3)$, so $l(t) = (1, 0, 3) + t \mathbf{d}$ for some direction $\mathbf{d}$.

The direction is perpendicular to both $(2, -1, 1)$ and $(2, 1, -4)$ (the latter following since $(2, 1, -4)$ is the normal of the plane), so we can take the cross product $$\mathbf{d} = (2, -1, 1) \times (2, 1, -4) = (3, 10, 4)$$

---

If you want to avoid the cross product, letting $\mathbf{d} = (x, y, z)$, we get:
$$\mathbf{d} \cdot (2, -1, 1) = 2x - y + z = 0 \implies y = 2x+z$$
$$\mathbf{d} \cdot (2, 1, -4) = 2x + y -4z = 4x - 3z = 0 \implies x = \frac{3}{4} z$$
We have a degree of freedom in choosing the magnitude of $\mathbf{d}$, so for sake of computation we set $z = 4$.

Then $x = 3, y = 10$ and so
$\mathbf{d} = (3, 10, 4),$
as before, and hence
$$l(t) = (1+3t, 10t, 3 + 4t)$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I really like how you went through both ways of computing $l(t)$.